# Uncaught ReferenceError: deactivate_links is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with my code, and as I'm new to this, I'm unsure how how to define this function in order to make it affect another Div. Here's the code, thanks in advance for the help.

```
<ul><div class="blah" id="info" onclick="active_link(this)">INFO
</div></ul>
<ul><div class="blah2" id="menu" onclick="active_link(this);deactivate_links(info)">MENU</div></ul>

<script type="text/javascript;">
function deactivate_links(obj) {
obj.style.color = "white";
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function active_link(obj) {
obj.style.color= 'red';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean to forget to include the end script tag `</script>`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I had it in the code, just copied and pasted one line too soon. Edited to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` of your `script` tag is incorrect.

It should be either just `<script>` or `<script type="text/javascript">` if you want to include the `type`.

Your final javascript code should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function active_link(obj) {
    obj.style.color= 'red';
  }
  function deactivate_links(obj) {
    obj.style.color = "white";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help with the syntax, but I'm still getting issues getting the "onclick" to fire. When "info" is clicked it turns red and remains that way, but upon clicking "menu" it will remain read while the menu also turns red giving the same error.

Comment: Did you define `active_link` anywhere in your code? If so, please add that to your question.

Comment: @TJ5897: You should not fix the mistakes that are the reason for your original question. Either way, `text/javascript;` is still incorrect as a type. If you followed this answer properly, you can see that your code "works": http://jsfiddle.net/05gbfmsa/. Note that having `div` elements as children of `ul` is invalid.

Comment: @TJ5897 I added the JavaScript that I am using to test your page. When I click on the MENU item the INFO item turns white as expected. This works in both Chrome and Firefox for me, but not IE.